# 2 different columns in same result

Tags: sql, join

```
select w15.player_name 
from world_cup_2015 w15 
join world_cup_2016 w16 on w15.player_id = w16.player_id;
```

and

```
select w15.player_name 
from world_cup_2015  w15 
left join  world_cup_2016 w16 on w15.player_id = w16.player_id 
where w16.player_id is null
```

Please could any one explain how to make out of these 2 queries as 2 different columns in same result?

Comment: 0


select w15.player_name from world_cup_2015 w15 join world_cup_2016 w16 on w15.player_id=w16.player_id;

-- This above query fetches one result -- assuming it as column_1
select w15.player_name from world_cup_2015 w15 left join world_cup_2016 w16 on w15.player_id=w16.player_id where w16.player_id is null

The second query fetches another result -- assuming it as column_2

Now these 2 queries should combined in such a way that I should get coloumn_1 and column_2 in single output

Share

Comment: You shouldn't have separate tables for each year. Have one, common table instead, for all years.

Comment: Please don't add important info as a comment, [edit] you question instead

Comment: Both your post & your comment are unclear. Clarify via edits, not comments. [mre] But clearly when this gets clear it's going to be a duplicate. Please before considering posting read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask], [Help] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use left join + case expressions to calculate column depending on `w16.player_id is null condition`

```
select case when w15.player_name w16.player_id is not null then w15.player_name end as col1,
       case when w15.player_name w16.player_id is null then w15.player_name end as col2 
  from world_cup_2015  w15 
       left join  world_cup_2016 w16 on w15.player_id=w16.player_id
```

Comment: I didn't get you sir

Comment: @kushobapavankumar okay, maybe I get it wrong what are you asking about. Please explain in details

Comment: @kushobapavankumar I mean that you can do it in single query because both queries are from the same tables. use left join and case expressions to calculate two columns